# Apache Require local and a couple of IPs

Tags: apache

i want to restrict an access to a page only to localhost as well as a couple of hosts.

i used to only allow it locally, atm i have :

```
<Location /server-status>
  SetHandler server-status
  Require local
  ProxyPass !
</Location>
```

can i add multiple Require values such as :

```
<Location /server-status>
  SetHandler server-status
  Require local
  Require ip 1.1.1.1 1.1.1.2 1.1.1.n
  ProxyPass !
</Location>
```

will it work ?

thanks
regards

Comment: You can add as many require directives as necessary, default behaviour is "any" so any match of the list will do. In any case, it is better to just try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of [the documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_host.html), multiple `Require` lines are permitted, so I cannot see why the combination of local and external addresses would be a bad thing.

Alternatively, you can adopt the `Allow`, `Deny`, and `Order` directives from `mod_access_compat`, but these are [deprecated](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html) in Apache v2.4 by the `Require` directive.